# Absurd error message when running LuaLaTeX from MikTeX bundle

Tags: fonts, luatex, miktex

From time to time I get a compilation stop for a fifteen-page article when using LuaLaTeX with an absurd diagnostics. LuaLaTeX reports that he did not have enough memory. At the same time, the task manager shows that 4GB of 16GB of memory is free in the system, and XeLaTeX compiles the article without problems. Releasing memory really helps restore compilations using LuaLaTeX. I have MikTeX and Windows 10 Professional. I didn’t check if LuaLaTeX from TeXLive works in the same conditions.

Actually, I do not know what to ask. It seems to me that this is some kind of tricky bug.

UPDATE:

Here is log:

```
\openout3 = DBubble-Note01Notes.bib
LaTeX Font Info:    Calculating math sizes for size <7.2> on input line 289.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/FiraMathRegular(1)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 5.03996pt on input line 289.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/FiraMathRegular(1)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 3.59999pt on input line 289.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/FiraMathRegular(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 5.0405pt on input line 289.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/FiraMathRegular(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 3.60037pt on input line 289.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/FiraMathRegular(3)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 5.03941pt on input line 289.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/FiraMathRegular(3)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 3.5996pt on input line 289.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/FiraMathRegular(1)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 8.0pt on input line 289.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/FiraMathRegular(1)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 6.0pt on input line 289.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/FiraMathRegular(1)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 5.0pt on input line 289.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/FiraMathRegular(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 8.00085pt on input line 289.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/FiraMathRegular(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 6.00064pt on input line 289.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/FiraMathRegular(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 5.00053pt on input line 289.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/FiraMathRegular(3)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 7.99915pt on input line 289.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/FiraMathRegular(3)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 5.99936pt on input line 289.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/FiraMathRegular(3)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 4.99947pt on input line 289.
<../Graph/Beklemishev2016PoP_23_082506_01.png, id=7, 755.07094pt x 256.70906pt>
File: ../Graph/Beklemishev2016PoP_23_082506_01.png Graphic file (type png)
<use ../Graph/Beklemishev2016PoP_23_082506_01.png>
Package luatex.def Info: ../Graph/Beklemishev2016PoP_23_082506_01.png  used on i
nput line 296.
(luatex.def)             Requested size: 246.0pt x 83.63313pt.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/FiraMathRegular(1)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.0pt on input line 300.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/FiraMathRegular(2)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.00096pt on input line 300.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/FiraMathRegular(3)/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 8.99904pt on input line 300.

Underfull \hbox (badness 4846) in paragraph at lines 300--300
[]\TU/FiraSans(0)/m/n/9 Рис. 1. [] Expansion of flux tubes at high $\TU/Fira
MathRegular(1)/m/n/9 $ \TU/FiraSans(0)/m/n/9 leads to
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 1675) in paragraph at lines 303--304
\TU/FiraSans(0)/m/n/10 in a linear trap at $\TU/FiraMathRegular(1)/m/n/10  
≈ 1$ \TU/FiraSans(0)/m/n/10 (or above the mirror-
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 1360) in paragraph at lines 303--304
\TU/FiraSans(0)/m/n/10 distribution across flux-tubes changes, so that the
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 1852) in paragraph at lines 303--304
\TU/FiraSans(0)/m/n/10 If the magnetic field of the trap is quasi-uniform
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 3260) in paragraph at lines 309--311
\TU/FiraSans(0)/m/n/10 В гид-ро-ди-на-ми-че-ском при-бл
и-же-нии вре-мя про-
 []

! error:  (lua): not enough memory
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The problem seems to go away when I substituted Fira fonts with STIX Two.

Comment: Since LuaTeX dynamically allocates memory, it might just be that your OS didn't give it enough memory in that split second for some obscure reasons.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I've added the log of event.

Comment: ooh you killed Lua, how did you do that? :-) It's only on line 311, so if you discard everything after that and whatever is before that that you can delete while still showing the error, can you post a complete document that shows the problem?

Comment: you seem to be loading a lot of math fonts at strange scales?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I am using just two commands: 
\setmainfont{Fira Sans}
and
\setmathfont[Color=000066,Scale=MatchLowercase]{Fira Math Regular}.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).